# Как делать классы-обёртки во FreePascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Я хочу задать дефолтное поле класса, к которому бы обращалась программа, при обращении напрямую к классу, например, так:

```
var
  Numbers: IntArr;

begin
  Numbers := IntArr.Create; //Создаём целочисленный динамический массив
  Numbers.add(5); //Добавляем число в конец массива
  Numbers.pull(42); //Добавляем число в начало массива
  Writeln(Numbers[0]); //Печатаем 42
  Numbers[1] := 84;
  Writeln(Numbers[1]); //Печатаем 84
end.
```

Можно ли реализовать такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам надо определить для своего класса `IntArr` **свойство** (property) с директивой `default`, установив ему методы чтения и записи из определённого там же поля, в котором вы храните ваш массив, вот так:

```
type
  IntArr = class
    private //Поля и методы из этого блока не могут быть вызваны из-за пределов класса.
      var
        IntArray: Array of integer; //Наш массив
      function GetEl(i: integer):integer; //Получить элемент массива
      procedure SetEl(i,Value: integer); //Задать элемент массива
    public //А из этого - могут
      property DefProp[i:integer]: integer read GetEl write SetEl;default;
      procedure add(Value: integer); //Добавить число в массив
      procedure pull(Value: integer); //Добавить число в начало массива
  end;

function IntArr.GetEl(i: integer):integer;
begin
  GetEl := IntArray[i];
end;

procedure IntArr.SetEl(i,Value: integer);
begin
  IntArray[i] := Value;
end;

procedure IntArr.add(Value: integer);
var
  l: integer;
begin
  l := length(IntArray)+1;
  SetLength(IntArray, l);
  IntArray[l-1] := Value;
end;

procedure IntArr.pull(Value: integer);
var
  i,l: integer;
  arr: Array of integer;
begin
  l := length(IntArray);
  SetLength(arr, l);
  for i:=0 to l-1 do arr[i] := IntArray[i];
  inc(l);
  SetLength(IntArray, l);
  IntArray[0] := Value;
  for i:=0 to l-2 do IntArray[i+1] := arr[i];
end;
```

К сожалению, есть два существенных ограничения:

1. Директива `default` применима только к индексированным свойствам
   (переменные-индексы перечисляются в квадратных скобках, после имени
   свойства, в нашем случае - `i:integer`). Попытка использовать её с
   обычным свойством, например так:

   ```
   property DefProp: integer read DefaultValue write DefaultValue;default;
   ```

   где `DefaultValue` - поле (переменная) класса, типа `integer`,
   вызовет ошибку компиляции.
2. Вытекает из первого: Как видно из примера в пункте 1, свойства могут
   обращаться при чтении и записи не только к методу (функции, для
   чтения, процедуре - для записи), но и к полю (переменной или
   константе, если для чтения) класса. Однако, индексированные свойства
   при чтении или записи обязаны передать, как параметр, индекс,
   поэтому могут обращаться только к методам.

**Обратите внимание:** Индексированные свойства могут иметь и более одного индекса,

```
property DefProp[n,m:integer]: integer read GetEl write SetEl;default;
```

что, для нашего примера, позволяет оборачивать в класс, в том числе, двумерные и многомерные массивы. Однако, синтаксис указания индексов у свойств и массивов отличается. Вместо

```
Writeln(Numbers[0][0]);
```

Для обращения к свойству следует писать:

```
Writeln(Numbers[0,0]);
```

Кроме того, вы **не сможете** получить весь массив, или строку двумерного массива простым обращением к свойсту так `Numbers` или так `Numbers[0]` (для двумерного массива), потому что свойство **не хранит никаких данных**, а лишь служит указателем, к какому методу или полю класса должна обратиться программа. Таким образом, опуская индекс вы лишь опустите обязательный аргумент функции, что, разумеется, приведёт к ошибке компиляции или выполнения.

Comment: возможно делать несколько индексированных свойств помеченных директивой default?

Comment: @Grundy - нет, невозможно